# Is there any map sdk for android phone which is missing google play services

Tags: android, sdk, google-play-services

Some android phones from China are not installed google play services. So, I can't use google map for them. I would like to know that is there any map sdk for the phone like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main flavours of Android that are not using Google Play Services. Amazon and Nokia forks of Android. But they provide their own Map SDKs. Do you know which kind of Android these phones run in China? If it's a fork by major players then they would be providing their own Map SDK as well.

That being said, OpenStreet map is a widely used open alternative of Google Maps and has a SDK that you can use. You can find more information on that here  https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid